# c# Exchange Webservices delete appointment in public folder

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, appointment

I trying to delete an appointment in an public calendar.

```
ExchangeService Exchange = new ExchangeService();
Uri tempuri = new Uri(@"\\192.168.55.138");
Exchange.Url = tempuri;
Exchange.AutodiscoverUrl("tp@mailserver.de");

string appointmentID = "AAIARgAAAA...";
Appointment deleteAppointmennt = Appointment.Bind(Exchange, new ItemId(appointmentID));
deleteAppointmennt.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);
```

But it doesn't work. Where is the problem?

Comment: could you try wrapping the deleteAppointmennt.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete) within a try catch and see what the error msg returns if any.. and post the error msg here..? also is there a public folder where the calendar appointments are held / stored in .. where are you pointing to the folder in your code if necessary..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out and let me know if it helps..

```
deleteAppointmennt.Delete(DeleteMode.SoftDelete, SendCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
```